# All enterable buildings in AC Syndicate?

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

Does anyone have a list of all the (or as many as you know) enterable buildings in Syndicate? (Excluding shops obviously) I've only come across the houses of parliament and Buckingham palace. I'm hoping there are a decent amount of interiors in this game as there aren't many in other open-worlds.
Thanks,
Harps.

Answer (score 3):

The following building categories are enterable as well:

- Pubs;
- Train Stations;
- Factories;
- Gentleman's clubs.
- Scotland Yard.

There are also a number of other buildings that can be entered as part of the storyline, which I'll mark as spoilers:

- > The hospital on the south side of London;
- > The Kenway mansion;
- > The tower of London;
- > Starrick's Syrop distillery;
- > The Bank of England;
- > The Alhambra.